# C# Webrequest upload file and proceed

Tags: c#, file, upload, webrequest

How can i upload a simple image to www.newocr.com, select a language from the combobox below , click the 'Upload' button and after the 'OCR' button and finnaly getting the string from the source code which stores the string into a id

All programatically. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow this link :

This Can Help You::

[OCR reading using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911484/ocr-reading-using-c-sharp)

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/157546/C-OCR-How-to-Read-a-single-character-from-image
Try This:

```
Bitmap BWImage = new Bitmap(fileName);
// Lock destination bitmap in memory
System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData BWLockImage = BWImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, BWImage.Width, BWImage.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);

// Copy image data to binary array
int imageSize = BWLockImage.Stride * BWLockImage.Height;
byte[] BWImageBuffer = new byte[imageSize];
Marshal.Copy(BWLockImage.Scan0, BWImageBuffer, 0, imageSize);
DoOCR(BWLockImage, BWImageBuffer, tmpPosRect, false);



// Do the OCR with this function
public string DoOCR(System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData BWLockImage, byte[] BWImageBuffer, Rectangle iAusschnitt, bool isNumber)
{
    Bitmap tmpImage = Bildausschnitt1bpp(BWLockImage, BWImageBuffer, iAusschnitt);
    string file = Path.GetTempFileName();
    string tmpResult = "";
    try
    {
        tmpImage.Save(file, ImageFormat.Tiff);
        _MODIDocument.Create(file);
        // Modi parameter erstellen
        _MODIDocument.OCR(MODI.MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH, false, false);

        MODI.IImage myImage = (MODI.IImage)_MODIDocument.Images[0]; //first page in file
        MODI.ILayout myLayout = (MODI.ILayout)myImage.Layout;
        tmpResult = myLayout.Text;
    }
    catch
    {
        if (_MODIDocument != null)
        {
            _MODIDocument.Close(false); //Closes the document and deallocates the memory.
            _MODIDocument = null;
        }
        // Bild freigeben
        tmpImage.Dispose();
        tmpImage = null;
        // Garbage Collector ausführen
        GC.Collect();
        // Bilddatei löschen
        File.Delete(file);
    }
    return tmpResult;
}
```

Comment: Actually i want to web request that website. If some one knows, just write it here the code, i'm making a project and this is the finnally thing i still need to do. So let me know.

Comment: I saw the website: www.newocr.com has a specific language character recognition which allows me to get the string from the image more easier, but i'm stuck web request it. Please some one need to help me doing the web request for this.

Comment: first upload your ocr image in this site second select your language third click on upload image button thant check your result

Comment: i did through firefox with tamper data, but how should i implement this in c#?

Comment: Any help guys? I'm very stucked in this and i really need to web request this website, is very important for me...

Comment: So i tried implementing this: http://cristiroma.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/how-to-programatically-upload-a-file-in-c-using-httpwebrequest/ and calling it like this: ImportUtilities.HttpUploadFile("http://www.newocr.com", "image.png", "paramName", "image/png", valueCollection); but i don't know what should i put in paramName and valueCollection

Comment: http://www.ocrwebservice.com/services/OCRWebService.asmx?op=OCRWebServiceRecognize

Comment: download project in this site   
ocrwebservice.com/support/DeveloperInformation.aspx

Comment: sign in this website that can be send all the details

Comment: oh it's just a 30 days trial and i need full, guys this webrequest for www.newocr.com is easier, so please help me doing this.

Comment: pankeel thanks for this new service but it's a trial, however can you help me trying to get the correct data from www.newocr.com ? right now im trying as i said before, but what are those 2 things? paramName and valueCollection. what are the values from the website?

Comment: sir, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067002/tesseract-3-ocr-net-wrapper follow this post newocr based on tesseract-3 so you check this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data for httpupload file

Comment: not quiet, not really understand what i need to put and how many in: nvc.Add("", "");

Comment: to you too ^_^ my friend